# Access Marketing Cloud assets in Social Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, social-content

Is there a way to access assets (images etc.) lying on Marketing Cloud Email App Portfolio from Social Studio. I want it in a marketer friendly way, with features like browsing.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Social Studio and Marketing Cloud are loosely connected at the moment, so there is no direct and easy way to access SFMC Portfolio (or Content Builder) items from Social Studio.

Social Studio has an [integration](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019Sy6QAE) with Advertising Studio in the Marketing Cloud, however. And that's it.

You may, though, create a 3rd party application that would make use of SFMC and Social Studio's APIs and there you could manage assets between two studious (Email and Social). API links are below:

**Social Studio API:** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_social.meta/api_social/1-introduction-to-the-social-studio-marketing-cloud.htm

**Marketing Cloud APIs:** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm